# Uniform convergence of a series through induction principle

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I'm working on [this](http://www.ism.ac.jp/editsec/aism/pdf/037_3_0541.pdf) paper. Can you please explain me the following passage of the proof that the series (2.9) converges uniformly?

Given:
$$
|\delta_{k+1}| \le \frac{\rho}{(k+1)}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}b^i\left|\delta_{k+1-i}\right|, \qquad k=0,1,2, \cdots
$$
it follows by induction that 
$$
|\delta_{k+1}| \le b^{k+1} \frac{\left(\rho\right)_{k+1}}{(k+1)!}
$$
where $(\rho)_k = \rho (\rho +1)\cdots(\rho + k -1), \quad \rho_0 = 1; \qquad \rho > 0; \qquad 0\le b < 1$

Please, take a look at the paper for more details.

Riccardo

Answer (score 1):

Assume the bound for $|\delta_k|$ is true. Then 
\begin{align}|\delta_{k+1}|&\leqslant \frac{\rho}{k+1}\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}b^i\frac{b^{k+1-i}(\rho)_{k+1-i}}{(k+1-i)!}\\
&=\frac{\rho b^{k+1}}{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^k\frac{(\rho)_j}{j!}.
\end{align}
Now use the fact that $\rho\frac{(\rho)_j}{j!}\leqslant \frac{(\rho)_{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$ for each $0\leqslant j\leqslant k$.

Comment: Thanks. So the bound is given, not derived somehow. And then it proves that this given bound actually bounds the series.